# How do I query a large time-series table in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, query

I have a Zabbix database with 2 tables, a `items` table that stores items, and a `history_text` table that stores time-series values about the `items`.

I am trying to create a query that will fetch the latest `value` from `history_text`, for each `item` that has a name that matches `^.*IP Address`.

I am facing a problem where my query is very slow, to the point where it doesn't return anything even after several minutes:

```
SELECT items.name, history_text.clock, history_text.value
FROM items
INNER JOIN history_text ON items.itemid=history_text.itemid
WHERE items.name REGEXP '^.*IP Address'
ORDER BY clock DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Table `history_text` with 36 million records:

```
CREATE TABLE `history_text` (
  `itemid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `clock` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `value` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `ns` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  KEY `history_text_1` (`itemid`,`clock`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Table `items` with 20K records:

```
CREATE TABLE `items` (
  `itemid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `snmp_oid` varchar(512) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `hostid` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `key_` varchar(2048) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `delay` varchar(1024) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `history` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '90d',
  `trends` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '365d',
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `value_type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `trapper_hosts` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `units` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `formula` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `logtimefmt` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `templateid` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `valuemapid` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `params` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `ipmi_sensor` varchar(128) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `authtype` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `username` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `publickey` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `privatekey` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `flags` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `interfaceid` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `inventory_link` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `lifetime` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '30d',
  `evaltype` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `jmx_endpoint` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `master_itemid` bigint(20) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `timeout` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '3s',
  `url` varchar(2048) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `query_fields` varchar(2048) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `posts` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `status_codes` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '200',
  `follow_redirects` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `post_type` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `http_proxy` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `headers` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `retrieve_mode` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `request_method` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `output_format` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `ssl_cert_file` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ssl_key_file` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `ssl_key_password` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `verify_peer` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `verify_host` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `allow_traps` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `discover` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `uuid` varchar(32) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`itemid`),
  KEY `items_1` (`hostid`,`key_`(1021)),
  KEY `items_3` (`status`),
  KEY `items_4` (`templateid`),
  KEY `items_5` (`valuemapid`),
  KEY `items_6` (`interfaceid`),
  KEY `items_7` (`master_itemid`),
  KEY `items_8` (`key_`(1024)),
  CONSTRAINT `c_items_1` FOREIGN KEY (`hostid`) REFERENCES `hosts` (`hostid`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `c_items_2` FOREIGN KEY (`templateid`) REFERENCES `items` (`itemid`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `c_items_3` FOREIGN KEY (`valuemapid`) REFERENCES `valuemap` (`valuemapid`),
  CONSTRAINT `c_items_4` FOREIGN KEY (`interfaceid`) REFERENCES `interface` (`interfaceid`),
  CONSTRAINT `c_items_5` FOREIGN KEY (`master_itemid`) REFERENCES `items` (`itemid`) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin
```

Comment: Should there be a `WHERE` clause in your `SELECT` query to filter on the IP address?

Comment: @dbdemon Yes, thank you, just edited to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

To put it bluntly, if you regularly need to look at a *substring*, break that out into a separate column.

Let's digress into the efficiency of that test.  All three of these perform equivalent tests.  The `LIKE` is the fastest, but still *not* fast enough for your needs.

```
REGEXP '^.*IP Address'
REGEXP 'IP Address'
LIKE '%IP Address%'
```

One way to "easily" provide the extra column that I recommend is to create a "generated" "persistent" column from `name LIKE '%IP Address%'`.  It will be a boolean (0 or 1).  Let's call this new column `has_ip`.  Then this index on `items` would at least avoid the scan of that table: `INDEX(has_ip, itemid)`.

I see that there is no explicit `PRIMARY KEY` for `history_text`, yet the one index is a likely way to reach into that table, correct?  Is `(itemid, clock)` Unique?  If so, make it the PK for a performance boost in it.  If not unique, we can talk further.

For further discussion, please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.